# Group elements according to one list and sum the corresponding entries in another list

Tags: performance, optimization, split, grouping, performance-testing

**Problem:** Given lists of integers `uu,ww` of same length, in Python 3 I wish to compute shorter lists u,w of same length, where u=unique elements of uu and w[i]=sum of all ww[j] such that uu[j]=u[i], i.e. accumulate the elements. For example, for `uu=[1,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,1,4]; ww=[0,4,2,1,6,3,2,6,3,0]` the output should be `[1,2,3,4],[7,13,7,0]`.

**Solution:** I have found these ways to achieve my goal:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools, collections
def ti(): return time.perf_counter() #current time
def acml(method,uu,ww): 
    if method==1: #result is not sorted
        d=collections.defaultdict(int)
        for i in range(len(uu)): d[uu[i]]+=ww[i]
        return list(d.keys()),list(d.values())
    if method==2: #result is sorted
        uw=list(zip(uu,ww)); #transposed list
        uw.sort(key=lambda x:x[0]); #sorted by zeroth coordinate
        uw=itertools.groupby(uw,lambda x: x[0]); #iterator
        uw=[[k,sum([i[1] for i in v])] for k,v in uw];
        return list(zip(*uw))
    if method==3: #slow, result is sorted
        x=pd.DataFrame(data={'u':uu,'w':ww}); x=x.groupby('u');
        u=[i for i,xi in x]; w=[xi['w'].sum() for i,xi in x]; return u,w
n=10**5; r=n//2; uu=list(np.random.randint(0,r,size=n)); ww=list(np.random.randint(-10,10,size=n));
t0=ti(); uw1=acml(1,uu,ww); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0)
t0=ti(); uw2=acml(2,uu,ww); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0)
t0=ti(); uw3=acml(3,uu,ww); t1=ti(); print(t1-t0)
```

Is there a faster function that achieves this? (the order of elements is irrelevant)

**Background:** The reason I need the function `acml` is that I am constructing a huge sparse matrix (of size up to 10^7 x 10^7 with a few entries per column). I do this by computing for each column `v` the entries `(u,w)`. Typically, there appear several such entries with the same first coordinate, and therefore the second coordinates of those elements should be summed.

I realize that the construction `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(ww,(uu,vv))` already takes care of this (i.e. it sums values belonging to the same location), but I would still like to use `acml`, because my matrices can barely fit into memory, so accumulating the entries of each column (before the entries of other columns are even found) would save up RAM.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason tu use lists over numpy arrays here? They use less memory and shold be the default type when working with scipy

Comment: @Miguel Well, given a `a=scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(...)` , its rows are lists (not numpy arrays) of entries.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I assumed that you would be working with csr or csc